# trivially default constructible std::optional and std::variant

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, option-type, variant

Is it permitable to design `std::optional` (currently `std::experimental::optional`) in such a way, that for trivially default constructible type `T` corresponding `std::optional< T >` is also trivially default constructible?

The same question regading `std::variant` and its integral discriminator.

My own answer is: "No, it cannot be designed in this way, because value of its integral discriminator obtained during default initialization will be indeterminate if the object has automatic storage duration or if it is `reinterpret_cast`-ed from non-zero-initialized storage." Requirement to the user to do value-initialization every time is not allowed on my mind.

Comment: Can I ask you in exchange why it is important to you? I can imagine why you would optional to be trivially-copyable. But why trivially-default-constructible? What does it buy you?

Comment: @Andrzej The container (like `optional` or `variant`) should be as generic as possible, isn't it? I attempt to design [`variant` for constexpr](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112218/trivial-full-fledged-variant-for-constexpr-proof-of-concept). And currently it has above ability. But I think "maybe I should to deny it?".

Comment: @Andrzej Eventually I found a "bug" in my `variant`. Default initialized objects has different behaviour in compile time (constexpr) and runtime. Then I read about [intiializations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization). And found out, that there is UB to use my default intiialized `variant` on the stack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your answer is correct: you cannot. The specification requires that its "initialized flag" is set to `false` upon default construction.

Answer (score 4):

As you explained yourself, you can't implement std::optional in such a way, because you would change its semantics (is_trivially_default_constructible is part of the class interface).

However, if you require this semantic for some reason in your code, there is no reason, why you couldn't implement a very similar optional class that is trivially default constructible. Then, when used, just zero initialize it via {} and - if that is what you want - treat zero as true in the bool operator.